# How to Act as Internet Explorer

Tags: cefsharp

I am using cefsharp in windows forms application. Somehow some sites need to run on internet explorer only. How can we set cefsharp (chromium) act like internet explorer?

I changed request headers to set user-agent like "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0; Windows NT 7.0; InfoPath.3; .NET CLR 3.1.40767; Trident/6.0; en-IN)" bu it did not solve my problem. The site still gets that the browser is not IE.

Could you please provide a solution?

Thanks for further help

Comment: If the sites is using `IE` specific features then you don't really have any out of the box options. You could rewrite some of the `JS` on the fly, though that would be very site specific. You'd be better to use the build in `WebBrowser` for those particular sites.

Comment: actually the site really does not need ie specific features. with cefsharp i need to fill the form automatically on this site. What i need, the site thinks that the browser is IE, not chrome. Once i log in the site, i can handle ie features via code. the site address is http://ergonet.ergoturkiye.com/portalWeb/welcome.jsf When i try to login

Comment: You'll need to analyse the source and determine how it detects the browser, come back once you've worked that out.

Comment: Here is the code for checking browser if (!document.all || !document.getElementById || !document.getElementsByTagName
  || !document.compatMode) {

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution as faking the site like adding missing property/funcs to document object in frameloadstart event like this.

```
        private void Browser_FrameLoadStart(object sender, FrameLoadStartEventArgs e)
    {
        browser.EvaluateScriptAsync(@"if(!document.all) { document.all = {};}  if(!document.compatMode) { document.compatMode = 'BackCompat'} if(!document.getElementsByTagName){ document.getElementsByTagName = function(){}; } ");
    }
```